# How to save the state of a UISwitch to file

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, nsuserdefaults

A similar question on stackoverflow yielded a combination of:

`NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   [userDefaults setBool:switchState forKey:@"mySwitchValueKey"];`

and

`BOOL swichState = [userDefaults boolForKey:@"mySwitchValueKey"];`

I've been trying to look into NSUserDefaults, but I understand neither what these pieces of code do, or where they should be in my program.

---

Could anyone tell me where they need to go? Why doesn't the code below work?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    BOOL switchState = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]  boolForKey:@"mySwitchValueKey"];
    if (switchState == YES) {
        [hard1ON setOn:TRUE];
    } else {
        [hard1ON setOn:FALSE];
    }
}

- (IBAction)switchValueChanged
{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setBool:switchState forKey:@"mySwitchValueKey"];

    if (hard1ON.on) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"theChange" object:nil];
    } else {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"theChange2" object:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: what you get if you put nslog(@"%d",switchState) in viewDidLoad.

Comment: nothing happens in the console

Comment: so your viewDidLoad is never called?

Comment: It logs 0 every time the view loads

Comment: in your switchValueChanged methd you used `setBool:switchState` from where is it getting switchState ?? is this an ivar/property?

Comment: when the switchValueChanged method is called i set switchState to 1

Comment: As in your code you have same variable in viewDidLoad as well, that's why i am asking is it a property, defined in .h ?

Comment: no it's not a property, should it be?

Comment: Yes it should be. And now i wonder how your compiler is not giving any error "Undefined symbol" for `switchState` in `switchValueChanged` methd!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First two lines are for saving your data, so on any submit/save button event you can use this lines to save your data. Or else you can save each time your switch value changes.
- Second line is for retrieving your saved data, so you can use this when your application gets re-lauched. So that you can get to know, what data has been saved in last launch. And according to that you can go ahead in your code.

For more details check this [link](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/), it might give you brief description about NSUserDefaults.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your response, could you please tell me why the edit to my question isn't working?

Comment: - (IBAction)switchValueChanged
{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setBool:<UISwitch outlet>.isOn forKey:@"mySwitchValueKey"];

Try this line of code

Comment: Have you got your required outcome now?

Comment: Just logged on to stackoverflow. Thanks for the help :) it's working

Answer (score 1):

These two statements are used  to create an instance of `NSUserDefaults` and then setting the `switchState` in `standardUserDefaults`, that is with your app.

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setBool:switchState forKey:@"mySwitchValueKey"];
```

`switchState` must be declared anywhere above this statement as `BOOL switchState`.

From this statement `BOOL swichState = [userDefaults boolForKey:@"mySwitchValueKey"];` the boolValue is read back into swichState.

The above code should be in the method that is invoked when you change or flip or move to aother view, assuming switchState is an local property to a class.

If it is a global or shared it can be any where, most suitable place would be `applicationSholdTerminate:`.

Comment: please see the edit to my question, could you tell me why it's not working?

Comment: @LouisHolley: while setting you should also use `[standardUserDefaults synchronize];`

Comment: in the viewDidLoad or the IBAction? It says standardUserDefaults is an undeclared variable

Comment: in switchValueChanged, use `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]`